# How to Play .wav File with JButton?

Tags: java, swing, audio, jbutton, embedded-resource

So recently, I have been trying to make my own Mario game (for myself, possibly to show my other friends). Games include buttons. When I click on a button in other games, it plays a sound. I would love to add that feature to my game. The problem is, it doesn't play. My source code is:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JButtonClick {

    JButton test = new JButton("Click Me!");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public void playSound(String soundName)
     {
       try 
       {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName).getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
         System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
         ex.printStackTrace( );
       }
     }


    public JButtonClick() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button-Click test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.add(test);

        test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
             playSound("JButton.wav");
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JButtonClick();
    }
}
```

My .wav file is in the same package as this class. But instead of it playing the sound I want, it just says this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\diego\workspace\Super Mario Bros 1\JButton.wav (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at JButtonClick.playSound(JButtonClick.java:21)
at JButtonClick$1.actionPerformed(JButtonClick.java:49)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Specifying the wrong path, perhaps?

Comment: Indeed, @JoshM speaks the truth. Please understand that you're trying to access the wav file as a file, and that the default directory is the directory of the `user.dir`, and that's not where you're looking. If possible, you should access the wav file not as a file but as a resource.

Comment: That resource is an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: Either use the full source path, or (at the very least) start from the root of your program. If your file is in the root folder, along with the sound, use `root/sound.wav`

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is usually thrown because the file was not found.

Comment: Once you get the file location issue worked out, remember that Clips is designed to be loaded just once, and played multiple times. Loading the audio into RAM introduces latency, as the load has to complete before playback can start. If you are only playing a sound file once, SourceDataLine is a better choice, as it has no loading-to-ram latency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem due to placement of your .wav file.

As per your question your have placed it in the same package as this class that's why you are getting `FileNotFoundException`.

Let me explain you how `new File(pathname)` works:

Javadoc about [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> A pathname, whether abstract or in string form, may be either absolute or relative. An absolute pathname is complete in that no other information is required in order to locate the file that it denotes. A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory.

- It you are running this application in eclipse then place .wav file directly in the project (outside `src` folder) as shown below:

  ```
  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("Jbutton.wav"));
  ```

[image]

- You can try also by placing it in `resource` folder.

  ```
  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("resources/Jbutton.wav"));
  ```

[image: Snapshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

> custom sounds play...using NetBeans..
>     First of all import some package or class name like this

```
   import java.applet.Applet;
   import java.applet.AudioClip;
   import java.net.URL;
```

Not working because generate Error on *`java.lang.NullPointerException`*

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("\\dbmsystem\\src\\sound\\Your_sound_name.wav");

URL url = getClass().getResource("G:\\zala\\dbmsystem\\src\\sound\\Your_sound_name.wav");
```

But Proper Working like this

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/sound/Your_sound_name.wav");    
AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
clip.play();
```