# Image, sound files in java, how to use them without full path

Tags: java

Can I use a filename to something in java without needing the full path? IE,

```
cashOutSound = Applet.newAudioClip(new URL("file:C:\\Users\\Wilson\\IdeaProjects\\Millionaire\\src\\sounds\\cashout.wav"));
```

Becomes problematic as I move my program across computers. Compiling to a jar doesn't seem to help.

Comment: [This link should contain all the answer you need](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html)

Comment: _Something_ needs to convert relative paths to absolute paths, and that is one of: the directory in which you run the program, or a configuration file that tells the program what to use as a base directory.  There's nothing magical that just reads the user's mind and finds the file regardless of where it is.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to Play .wav File with JButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430970/how-to-play-wav-file-with-jbutton?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
URL url = getDocumentBase();

AudioClip audioClip = getAudioClip(url, "music/JButton.wav")
```

Project sturcture

[image]

---

Sample code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

public class PlaySoundsApplet1 extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Button play, stop;
    private AudioClip audioClip;

    public void init() {

        URL url = getDocumentBase();
        audioClip = getAudioClip(url, "music/JButton.wav");

        play = new Button("Play");
        add(play);
        play.addActionListener(this);
        stop = new Button("Stop");
        add(stop);
        stop.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Button source = (Button) ae.getSource();
        if (source == play) {
            audioClip.play();
        } else if (source == stop) {
            audioClip.stop();
        }
    }
}
```